# Why is my if statement not working for all the mysql results?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

So I've been trying to put an if statement inside my while loop. Now I'm not really very knowledgeable but as I looked around I don't see anything wrong with this.. I placed the if statement outside and inside but the if statement only works for one entry even if there are three entries.

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res))
   {

        if (isset($r[3])) {$urlvalue =  $r[3];
            $disable ='<script>
            document.getElementById("adurl").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("update").disabled = true;
            </script>';
        }
            else {$urlvalue = "";}

     print "<tr><form style='text-align:center;' method='post' action='loginspotlight.php'>";
     print "<td style='text-align:center;'>$r[0]</td><td style='text-align:center;'>$r[1]</td><td style='text-align:center;'>$r[2]</td><td style='text-align:center;'><input id='adurl' name='adurl' type='url' value='$urlvalue'/></td><td style='text-align:center;'>$r[4]</td><td style='text-align:center;'>$r[5]</td><td>";
     print "<input align='center' type='hidden' value='$r[0]' name='spotid'/>";
     print "<div width='100px'><input id='update' align='center' type='submit' name='cmd' value='Update'/><div>$disable</div></div>";
  print "</td></form></tr>";                 
   }
 print "</table><br><br>";
```

It looks like this :
[image]
Hope you can help me out! I'll be sanitizing all $_POST values for mysql as well.

Comment: What is `var_dump($r)`? Also, ***do not use mysql_*** - learn to use mysqli or pdo with prepared statements instead

Comment: That's what I was planning, I'm a beginner so I'm trying to wrap as much info about mysql functions around my head. Once I'm done with that, I'll be converting my sql queries to mysqli or prepare them. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: `I'll be sanitizing all $_POST values for mysql as well.` If I had a nickel...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the same ID for multiple elements.

Instead of calling javascript to be executed, why not just disable the element directly as you're outputting it?

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res))
   {

        if (isset($r[3])) 
        {
            $urlvalue =  $r[3];
            $disabled = 'disabled="disabled"';
        }
        else 
        {$urlvalue = "";}

     print "<tr><form style='text-align:center;' method='post' action='loginspotlight.php'>";
     print "<td style='text-align:center;'>$r[0]</td><td style='text-align:center;'>$r[1]</td><td style='text-align:center;'>$r[2]</td><td style='text-align:center;'><input id='adurl' name='adurl' type='url' value='$urlvalue' $disabled/></td><td style='text-align:center;'>$r[4]</td><td style='text-align:center;'>$r[5]</td><td>";
     print "<input align='center' type='hidden' value='$r[0]' name='spotid'/>";
     print "<div width='100px'><input id='update' align='center' type='submit' name='cmd' value='Update' $disabled/><div>$disable</div></div>";
    print "</td></form></tr>";                 
   }
 print "</table><br><br>";
```

Alternatively, you could put the query result's ID into the element's ID to make it unique.

For example:

```
$disable = '<script>document.getElementById("update_' . $r[0] .'").disabled = true;</script>';
print '<input id="update_' . $r[0] . '" type="text"/>';
print $disable
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, thank you! The only thing I changed is :

if (empty($r[3])) 
        {
            $urlvalue = "";
        $disabled = 'enabled';
            
        }
        else 
        {$urlvalue =  $r[3];
            $disabled = 'disabled';
            
        }

Comment: Great to hear it's working for you! A good habit to build, is to try not to rely on javascript to set your page into its initial state. If you're outputting the HTML, you should try to output it in whatever state you need it to be in. If you're comfortable with this solution, don't forget to indicate that the question is answered!

Comment: Is it possible to completely delete the button if $r[3] was set?

Comment: You could put your `print` statement that outputs the button inside of an `if` statement that does the $r[3] check. In other words, only output the button if $r[3] is not set. `if (!isset($r[3])) {print '<input type="button" />';}`